# learning rate decay in LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm

I am currently reproducing the code for char-RNN described in http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/. There are codes already implemented in tensorflow and the code I am referring to is at https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow/blob/master/train.py I am having a question for the learning rate decay.In the code the optimizer is defined as an AdamOptimizer. When I went through the code, I saw a line as following:

```
for e in range(args.num_epochs):
        sess.run(tf.assign(model.lr, args.learning_rate * (args.decay_rate ** e)))
```

which adjusts the learning rate by a decay constant. 
My question is: isn't Adam optimizer making us able to control the learning rate? Why do we still use a decay rate with respect to learning rate here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean RMSprop and not Adam, both of the codes you linked use RMSprop. [RMSprop](http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#rmsprop) only scales gradients to not have too large or too small norms. So, it is important to decay the learning rate when we have to slow down training after several epochs.